# Are there any regular holiday events?

Tags: diablo-iii

Yesterday I was doing some bounties when noticed that one of them was to kill  [Vicious Gray Turkey](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Vicious_Gray_Turkey). My thought was that it's related to Thanksgiving holiday in the US this week. I've searched a bit for details, but was only able to find [this vague thread from 2014](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/15353796539).

Are there any special quests/rewards/challenges for this or other holidays in game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are only a few special events in Diablo 3 that I'm aware off.

Last year, at the end of the year, they did a [20 year anniversary celebration of Diablo](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/20407578/blizzard-celebrates-20-years-of-diablo-12-28-2016)  Its possible they may bring it back this year.

Other than that, they occasionally do an event called [Double Trouble](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/15487813/double-your-treasure-double-your-fun-8-26-2014) where all treasure goblins spawn in pairs.  This is not a regularly scheduled event but it does come back around every once in a while.  They just had one right before season 12 started.

The vicious gray turkey is not part of any thanksgiving festivities, he's been around for a while now.  You need to kill him as part of a cheevo for killing all the unique named monsters.

Comment: There are only two truly seasonal events: aforementioned Anniversary, available through January, and [Kanai's memorial event](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Udder_Cowlamity), available through March.

Comment: Diablo 1 event is [confirmed](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/20752429683#post-19) to be repeated every January.